# "Rather than"-construction

Tags: grammar

I found these two sentences which seem to me to be quite similar in the translation but are constructed in a different way:

> 1. 魚を食べる **ぐらいなら** 飢えたほうがましだ
>      'I rather starve than eat fish.'
> 2. 恥 **よりも** 死ぬほうがましだ。
>      'To die is better than to be in shame.'

Can anybody explain about the difference? Sorry, my English isn't that good; maybe the translation of the sentences is bit poor.

Comment: There is no difference in the structure of the two Japanese sentences.  You should consider how the two English sentences are different.  The first example is not translated as “To starve is better than to eat fish” because doing so makes the sentence sound like an absolute truth applicable to everyone, but it has nothing to do with the structure of the Japanese sentence.

Comment: ?? "I rather starve than eat fish" means 魚を食べるくらいなら飢える（or飢え死にした）方がましだ, no?　(I mean... which are you saying is better, to starve or to eat fish?)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto:  I feel like you should have made your response an answer.

Comment: @istrasci: You may be right, but I am not sure because it seems more like I am talking about English rather than Japanese, and I do not think that I am the right person to answer questions about English….

Comment: @all:Thank you very much for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Ok, I can see that the first sentence is more a "personal point of view" while the second tells about a common wisdom. Is it like that because ぐらいなら is more "vage" than "よりも...ほうが? I know about より but not really about ぐらいなら (=approximately?) Would be fine if you could explain more about the difference between these two.

Comment: @Flaw: Yes, obviously より is not present in the first sentence;-It seems as if you know the difference between this one and the one taught in textbooks. Let me know, please!

Comment: @Chocolate: I am sorry but I dont understand the connection to my question.

Comment: @istrasci: Sorry but I feel like Tsuyoshi TRIED to answer my question. Did you?
I am still new to this site but I noticed there is often kind of a subtle agression and a tendency to rather "counsel" people about their communication skills than referring to questions.
I dont want to offend, its just my impression.

Comment: @ Sawa: Thanks for editing, looks much better like this:-)

Comment: @Pegasus Lol so you don't even remember the original Japanese sentence you wrote in your question. Last time I saw this thread it was 飢えるくらいなら魚を食べたほうがましだ, but nevermind, seems like Sawa-san or somebody has edited it.

Comment: @Pegasus: About istrasci’s comment: I think that you have misunderstood what istrasci meant.  What he meant is that I should have posted my comment as an answer instead of a comment.  Maybe he is right, but I am not sure because of the reason I wrote in my reply to him.

Comment: @Chocolate: You are keen!  I did not realize that error in the question when I wrote my first comment.

Comment: Personally I was always a fan of むしろ auxiliary as in [恥を受けることよりも、むしろ死んだ方がいい！」 \*grin\*

Comment: Pegasus, Chocolate, TsuyoshiIto: In the original question, the Japanese sentence and the English translation did not match. The arguments were entirely switched. I wondered whether to fix the Japanese sentence to match the translation or to fix the translation to match the Japanese sentence. Seeing that people have commented based on the translation, I fixed the Japanese sentence.

Comment: 飢えるくらいなら魚を食べたほうがましだ seems better to me than 魚を食べる ぐらいなら 飢えたほうがましだ. The English expression that best catches the nuance is probably 'You might as well eat fish as starve'. The implication is that eating fish is the better of two evils. You might not like eating fish, but it's better than starving. I got these from the Internet: こんな生活をするくらいなら、一人で外国へ行ったほうがいい。/ 悪いことをして金持ちになるくらいなら、貧乏な生活をしたほうがいい。/ こんな仕事をして生活するくらいなら、国へ帰ったほうがいい。/ あの人と結婚するくらいなら、死んだほうがましだ。 / 家事をたまにしかしないくらいなら、全然しないほうがましだと思う。In all of these cases the suggestion is to avoid something truly bad. Surely eating fish is better than starving!

Comment: @crunchyt-san, Hmm, I don't think we usually say 恥を'受ける'... Probably it'd be more like 恥を'さらす'よりも/恥を'さらすくらいなら' or 恥を'かく'よりも/恥を'かくくらいなら'?

Comment: @Bathrobe-san, Yeah... but marrying someone is better than dying, no?

Comment: Chocolate:You are right, I did not notice Sawa had changed the sentence, too.
Thanks a lot, everybody! I understand that the problem was my bad translation. Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @ Chocolate
hehe, maybe...

Comment: People, this is the **comments** section, to raise *concise* points related to the question. **NOT** 1) for chatting 2) to post answers 3) to nitpick and argue back and forth. This post has 20 comments, and at a cursory glance, this is about 15 too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まし is usually used to mean "preferable" in the "less bad" sense, i.e. you're choosing the lesser of two evils. ぐらいなら reinforces this point, i.e.

> 魚を食べるぐらいなら飢えたほうがましだ If I had to go as far as eating fish, starving would be less bad.

ぐらい can come after nouns as well, but with this specific nuance, it is not often used after nouns. So we could say

> 恥をかくぐらいなら死んだほうがましだ Dying is preferable to facing disgrace

However, if we're using the noun 恥, it would be more natural to rephrase to よりも (or よりは)

> 恥よりも死のほうがましだ Death is preferable to disgrace

By the way, your example sentence is comparing a noun to a verb, 恥 and 死ぬ. While maybe not exactly wrong, I feel rewriting 死ぬ to the noun 死 sounds better.

Beware that ぐらい can also be used in the opposite sense, to reinforce that something is easy or small (like "only"). In this sense, it's used after nouns as well

> ちょっと待つぐらいならいい I don't mind waiting (if it's only) for a bit
>   ケーキ五個ぐらいなら食べられる If it's only 5 cakes, I can eat them

Comment: Is the kanji 恥 read はじ or じょく? Please consider putting in furigana if you can. :)

Comment: @DaveMG http://jigen.net/kanji/24677 How did you come up with じょく? Maybe you're thinking of 辱?

Comment: じょく comes up as one of the readings for 恥 in WWWJDIC.

Comment: @DaveMG Should be 「はじ」.  Looking at the context (the other item being compared is a Japanese-style usage of 死,) can often also help you make your guess on readings.