# What's the meaning of 位 when it follows ことをする a.k.a. "to do something"?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for help with the meaning of 位 in this sentence

> **Hawk:**「一軒でも来なかったという家があったら、もう貴様もその時がおしまいだぞ。」
> **Nightjar:**「だってそれはあんまり無理じゃありませんか。そんなことをする**位**なら、私はもう死んだ方がましです。」

My only guess is that ことをする位 translates as "do something of a certain rank/social standing". (e.g. "How could you do something so low class?")
Which makes my reading:

> **Hawk:** "If there is even one house that says you did not come, then at that time I will end you also!"
> **Nightjar:** "You say that is not very unreasonable?! If you will do such a thing *of that* **rank** then I would rather be dead [than do what you tell me to]."

Is that reading of 位 correct?

**EDIT**:
According to Chocolate, the correct reading is "to that extent". See http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84 
for the definition (it *isn't* listed under 位).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between くらいなら ～ のほうがましだ and くらいなら ～ ほうがいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30329/difference-between-%e3%81%8f%e3%82%89%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%ef%bd%9e-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a0-and-%e3%81%8f%e3%82%89%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%ef%bd%9e-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%84)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4760/9831

Comment: The くらい is not the noun "rank" but an adverbial particle "to that extent" or "so much"

Comment: I'm guessing if it had been written in kana there might have been no question, right, @Hyperglyph?

Comment: @Chocolate, The Duplicate question seems to be about ~ましだ vs. ~いい when using 位. My question is specifically about 位 itself. The 2nd linked question is closer to what I was asking. Anyway, I guess the correct reading here would be "If you go to the extent of doing such a thing".

Comment: @mamster, **Snap** I just realized the "extent" definition is on Jisho under くらい but not the kanji. Well, now I feel stupid.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound snarky at all! Words that are only rarely written in kanji trip me up all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is some discussion in the comments but since it's not an exact dupe I think a proper answer should be in order.]

This 位 is read `ぐらい` (or `くらい`, it seems both readings are used equally often) and is usually used to express an amount, extent, or degree of something. With verbs it could be interpreted "as far as X goes...". So, the quoted part could be translated as:

> そんなことをする位なら、私はもう死んだ方がましです。
>
> As far as doing such thing(s) goes, dying would be better for me.
>
> → *I'd rather die than do something like that.*

Here's a nice blog post listing many examples and usage patterns of this word:

http://maggiesensei.com/2011/01/26/request-lesson-%E4%BD%8D-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%EF%BC%8F%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-kuraigurai/